# How to turn up Bass on android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am building an MP3 Player. I need to know how to add Bass Boost to my app.

Comment: You should give some code what you have tried and explain what is not working!

Comment: I have tried this approach:

Comment: BassBoost bbo = new BassBoost(0,mp.getAudioSessionId());
  bbo.setEnabled(false);
  BassBoost.Settings bboSettingTemp =  bbo.getProperties();
  BassBoost.Settings bboSetting = new BassBoost.Settings(bboSettingTemp.toString());
  bboSetting.strength = 1000; // 1000
  bbo.setProperties(bboSetting);

  bbo.setStrength((short) 100); // progress value from seek bar
  
  bbo.release();

Comment: Please [edit] your post. Comments are not for code

Comment: I dont know how to comment code XD

Comment: Plus I already solved it, thanks to CodeWalker.

Answer (score 0):

```
bassBoost = new BassBoost(0, 0);
bassBoost.setEnabled(true);

if (bassBoost.getStrengthSupported())
{
    short word1 = bassBoost.getRoundedStrength();
    bassBoost.setStrength(word1);
}
```

Comment: I have tried that too. I did not hear a difference.

Comment: Its now not wroking. Here is my log cat:

Comment: 08-21 12:14:48.945: E/MediaPlayer(22039): error (1, -38)
08-21 12:14:48.949: E/MediaPlayer(22039): invoke failed: wrong state 0
08-21 12:14:48.960: E/MediaPlayer(22039): Error (1,-38)
08-21 12:14:48.960: E/MediaPlayer(22039): Error (1,-1010)

Answer (score -2):

To quote CodeWalker,
I had to implement this

```
bassBoost = new BassBoost(0, 0);
bassBoost.setEnabled(true);

if (bassBoost.getStrengthSupported())

{
short word1 = bassBoost.getRoundedStrength();
bassBoost.setStrength(word1);
}
```

But as it turns out, bassBoost.getRoundedStrength() returns a value of zero, so the developer must set it themselves, or allow the user to.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.